# proportion formula google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

im am still doing my google sheets test and need help finding the answer to the question: what proportion of products are discontinued. i have to express my answer in a formula on google sheets

you can find the link to the data stack here:

products list:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m67VmLZispyTwFTmPdppsdJNtbvnZsZK2LBCSchUWmU/edit?usp=sharing

my idea was to count the 0 in the column J(discontinued) with the formula: =Countif(J2:J78,"0"). in the next step i would have to show a proportionality and i have no clue how i am supposed to do that. could anyone tell me if the first step is correct and how i should go about the proportionality?

thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the formula [PERCENTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9983035?hl=en):

> Returns the percentage of a range that meets a condition.
> `PERCENTIF(range, criterion)`

In this case if you want to know the percentage of 0 this would be:

`=PERCENTIF(J2:J78;"0")`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any formula, just build a pivot table
[image]